# Struggling with string split and regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, oop, split, bluej

in a new BlueJ(java) project I have 4 classes:
First some info about my project,
I'm following a tutorial task where the main goal is to learn to work with error handling,
but I'm not at that part quite yet, I am working with establishing the main classes.
Thats what I need a little help and guidance with,(but errors are supposed to come up and be detected
so that I can learn to fix them later, but that's not the main question here, just information.)
Here's 3 of the classes which I've completed.
Student with two private fields: Name name and CourseCollection course.
Name with two fields String firstName and String surname.
CourseCollection with ArrayList  courses.

(Info: Later, I will work with class UserDatabase to collect and load a collection of students,
+ class DatabaseFormatException which will represent errors, but I think it would be easier to finish those 3 classes above first? Correct me if 
I'm wrong.)

QUESTION: I need help with the class CourseCollection. It has an ArrayList with text values representing course codes.
They are not supposed to contain ; symbols!

The second constructor public CourseCollection(String coursesEncoded)..
I am not really sure what this constructor should do, to be honest. I figured, maybe I should
initialise the exclusion of ; symbols already here.
You can see what I tried. It shows an error with
list.replaceAll. I don't understand why this doesn't work, or if it shouldn't be coded this way for my purpose?
I have used a regex, but I am not experienced with this,

The method public String encode() should return a text value of the whole collection.
Every course code should end with a ; (maths;science;). 
I have tried to use a string split by adding the courses and then splitting them with ;
The main error I found is highlighted in the code. (string next line split)

The method public void addCourse(String courseCode) is adding a new course,
but if the parameter is null or contains a ; it will throw a IllegalArgumentException
If the course is already in the list it should throw an AssertionError and crash the program by an assert statement.
This method doesnt show any errors, but I'm still not sure if it's correct.

Thanks in advance, I find
people on StackOverflow to be very helpful as I don't have anyone (other than my books)
to ask for help.

```
 public class CourseCollection
 {
// instance variables, an ArrayList containing courses as String values.
private ArrayList < String > courses;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class CourseCollection
 */
public CourseCollection()
{
    courses = new ArrayList < > ();
}

/**
 * ?Making sure the elements in the list doesn't contain any ; symbols?
 */
public CourseCollection(String coursesEncoded)
{
List<CourseCollection> list = new ArrayList<CourseCollection>();
String myRegex = "[;]";
int index = 0;
for (CourseCollection c : list)
{
//Here is an error cannot find method replaceAll
list.replaceAll(myRegex, "\\\\");
}

}

   /**
* Returning one text value, representing the whole collection.
* Every course(text) is supposed to be ended with a ; 
* Example: Maths;Science;
*/
   public String encode()
{
   //Representing the collection as text
   String encode = Arrays.toString(courses.toArray());
      while (true){
    System.out.println(courses);
    //Here is an error, cannot find symbol string
    String line = string.nextLine().split(";");
    courses.add(line);
    String[] courses = line.split(" ; ");
   }
   }

   /**
*Adding courses to the collection, with some exceptions:
*If the parameter is a null object, 
*or contains a ; throw IllegalArgumentException
*
*If the course already exist in the list, throw AssertionError
*and the program should crash. This should happen after an
*assert assumption.
*/
   public void addCourse (String courseCode)
   {

   //Is this wrong by creating a new list??
   ArrayList<String> allcourses = new ArrayList<String>();
   allcourses.add("Maths");
   allcourses.add("Science");

   System.out.println("Courses" + allcourses);

   //Making sure it throws IllegalArgumentException if it contains a ;
   //or the parameter is a null object
   for (int i = 0; i < allcourses.size(); i++)
   if (allcourses.get(i).contains(";")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
       } else if (allcourses.get(i)== null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < allcourses.size(); i++)
   if (allcourses.contains("\\.")) {
       //If the list already contains any of the text values I want to add,
   //I want to throw an assertion error- but this should happen as a result
   //of an assert allegation! I think this is wrong.
       throw new AssertionError();
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you compact this into a smaller example? Like what is an example of the contents of your `ArrayList`, and what should it then be after you make your change to it? Might make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your description, I edited your code like below :

```
 public class CourseCollection {
// instance variables, an ArrayList containing courses as String values.
private ArrayList<String> courses;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class CourseCollection
 */
public CourseCollection() {
    courses = new ArrayList<>();
}

/**
 * ?Making sure the elements in the list doesn't contain any ; symbols?
 */
public CourseCollection(String coursesEncoded) {
    this();
    String myRegex = "[;]";
    coursesEncoded = coursesEncoded.replaceAll(myRegex, "\\\\");
    this.addCourse(coursesEncoded);
}

/**
 * Returning one text value, representing the whole collection.
 * Every course(text) is supposed to be ended with a ;
 * Example: Maths;Science;
 */
public String encode() {
    return String.join(";", courses);
}

/**
 * Adding courses to the collection, with some exceptions:
 * If the parameter is a null object,
 * or contains a ; throw IllegalArgumentException
 * <p>
 * If the course already exist in the list, throw AssertionError
 * and the program should crash. This should happen after an
 * assert assumption.
 */
public void addCourse(String courseCode) {

    if (courseCode == null || courseCode.contains(";"))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

      if(courses.contains(courseCode)){
       throw new AssertionError();
      }

    // if everything is fine
    courses.add(courseCode);


}
}
```

I tested in a few examples and it worked for me